# jQuery slide - CSS issue in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have this simple flyer page which uses jquery to reveal a form via two buttons that when clicked call `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`.

It works fine in all browsers except IE.

The site is:  http://atlas.jgregorydesigns.com/

The isse is : Once a button is clicked the buttons get pushed down and out of position messing  up the page layout. The buttons then disappear after being clicked again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made the unfortunate mistake of not including a doctype to escape [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Add this as the very first line, and it works fine in Internet Explorer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You should *always* have a doctype.

Comment: WOW you are a life saver. I would never have thought of that. Thanks!